# beautifulsoup: unable to find expected values

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm attempting to use beautifulsoup to parse out my schedule from the company website. [Example site](https://www.floydsbarbershop.com/leetsdale/) (not my own, for privacy purposes):

[image: screenshot]

I've tried iterating through the different classes in hopes of finding my information, but I can't.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.floydsbarbershop.com/leetsdale').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')

match = soup.find_all('span',class_='name')
for item in match:
    print(item)
```

When I run that code, I don't find any actual name values. I'm hoping to be able to iterate through each name until I find mine and then go through the remaining bits to pull down my schedule data.

Comment: What do you mean 'I don't find any actual name values'? Are there None? Is nothing printed? Is there an error message? What does `print(len(list(match))` print (before the loop)?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.floydsbarbershop.com/modules/staff/ajax.aspx"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
data={"FromDayFormat": "ddd - MMM d", "ToDayFormat": "ddd d", "StartDay": "0", "EndDay": "7", "LocationId": "31", "F": "GetScheduleForLocation"}
source = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).json()

for data_raw in source:
    print(data_raw["Name"])
```

you're sending the post request to the wrong link *(you don't really need beautifulsoup)*

---

**With Schedules:**

If you want to also access their schedules printed try using the following code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.floydsbarbershop.com/modules/staff/ajax.aspx"

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0"}
data={"FromDayFormat": "ddd - MMM d", "ToDayFormat": "ddd d", "StartDay": "0", "EndDay": "7", "LocationId": "31", "F": "GetScheduleForLocation"}
source = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data).json()

for data_raw in source:
    for schedule in data_raw['ScheduleDays']:
        if not(schedule['FromHour'] == None):
            print(f"{data_raw['Name']} is working on {schedule['DayRange']} from {schedule['FromHour']}{schedule['FromHourDayPart']} to {schedule['ToHour']}{schedule['ToHourDayPart']}")
    print("----------")
```

*(PS: you can removed `print("----------")` if you don't need it)*

Hope this helps!

Comment: doesn't work. i think the page is dynamically loaded, which is why beautifulsoup isn't pulling the data. now i'm trying to figure out how to configure selenium to pull the data

Comment: @user3654225 I've just updated my code, it should work now (good news, it's not dynamically loaded)

Comment: okay so i'm new to this, that pulled the names, how do i go about pulling the schedule data?

Comment: @user3654225 no worries, I just updated my code. is this what you wanted?